# How can I get more gain from a cascaded Sallen-Key filter without an additional opamp?

Tags: operational-amplifier, filter, active-filter

I am attempting to understand Sallen-Key filters with regards to shaping small current pulses into Gaussian form. I have put together a cascaded filter in SPICE (apologies for clutter):

[image: schematic]

Input pulse (nanosecond rise time, 100s microsecond decay):

[image: input]

U3 (green), U4 (blue) output (2.4us FWHM):

[image: output]

- Input: 140mV tailpulse (10ns rise, 100us decay)
- Output(U3): 580mV gaussian (2.4us FWHM)
- Gain: ~4

I would like to get the gain closer to 10. This was easy enough by adding U4:

- Input: 140mV tailpulse (10ns rise, 100us decay)
- Output(U4): 1.2V gaussian
- Gain: ~8

I would like to get the same gain increase without using the additional opamp. Adding a feedback resistor on U2 was a noob thing to try, but here is the result:

[image: noob]

This suggests, loudly, that other components need to be adjusted if I am to get gain from U2. I suspect R2/3/5 and possibly C4. Any suggestions on where to focus are greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can make S-K filters [with gain](http://sim.okawa-denshi.jp/en/OPseikiLowkeisan.htm), but there is a limit. However, you should know their weak point: at high frequencies they provide direct output feedback through the capacitor, influencing the response. I would suggest multiple feedback (same page), which also allow for more gain.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do/achieve @earl

Comment: @Andyaka I am trying to get more gain out the circuit (U3 output) without adding the last opamp (U4)

Comment: Well, dump the filters or explain why you want to filter the signal <--- this is what I am trying to understand.